# Java-8: stream or simpler solution?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have two models, a `List<ModelA>` and I want to convert it to a `List<ModelB>`. 
Here are my models:

```
class ModelA {

    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private Integer value;

    public ModelA(Long id, String name, Integer value) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Integer getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}

class ModelB {
    private Long id;
    private Map<String, Integer> valuesByName;

    public ModelB(Long id, Map<String, Integer> valuesByName) {
        this.id = id;
        this.valuesByName = valuesByName;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public Map<String, Integer> getValuesByName() {
        return valuesByName;
    }
}
```

Actual solution:

```
public static List<ModelB> convert(List<ModelA> models) {
        List<ModelB> toReturn = new ArrayList<>();
        Map<Long, Map<String, Integer>> helper = new HashMap<>();
        models.forEach(modelA -> {
            helper.computeIfAbsent(modelA.getId(), value -> new HashMap<>())
                    .computeIfAbsent(modelA.getName(), value -> modelA.getValue());
        });
        helper.forEach((id, valuesByName) -> toReturn.add(new ModelB(id,valuesByName)));
        return toReturn;
    }
```

But I think there is a simpler solution, do you have any idea how can I do it in a single stream, or simplify it somehow?

**EDIT**: I want to clarify that I **cannot** use java9 and I need to group them by Id-s then by Name. If in ModelB I have 4 elements with the same id I don't want new instances of ModelA.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have combined both operations, but still constructs the intermediate map as you need to *group* all **name, value** pairs for a given **id**.

```
models.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(model -> model.getId(), //ModelA::getId - Using method reference
                Collectors.toMap(model -> model.getName(), model -> model.getValue(), (map1, map2) -> map1)))
        .entrySet()
        .stream()
        .map(entry -> new ModelB(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**EDIT:**

I missed `(map1, map2) -> map1` in the initial answer. It is needed to avoid overwriting the already existing `value` for a `id`, `name`(the equivalent of your second `computeIfAbsent` in your code)
You need to choose one of them (or mege them), as by default it throws `IllegalStateException` when it finds a duplicate key.

Comment: Wait a second. Don't you have to actually merge maps instead of just choosing one?

Comment: It works perfectly. Reacting to the Edit part, it is okay without the merging function, because name-s are unique for the ids, I wont have the same name at the same Id.

Comment: @lexicore It is the case of having two modelA objects like [1, "a", 1] and [1, "a", 2]. In this case, since the OP is using `computeIfAbsent` for the key "a" value 2 won't be put in the map

Comment: @Sunflame okay. I used it going as per your existing code.

Comment: @lexicore I have created an [example](https://ideone.com/RfhkA2) for easier visualization. Notice [2, "c", 3] and [2, "c", 4]

Answer (score -1):

This is easily achieved using the `map` function from [Stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html):

```
public static List<MobelB> convert(List<ModelA> models) {
  Map<Long, Map<String, Integer>> modelAMap = models.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(ModelA::getId, modelA -> computeMap(modelA)));

  return models.stream()
    .map(modelA -> new ModelB(modelA.getId(), modelAMap.get(modelA.getId())))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

private static Map<String, Integer> computeMap(ModelA model) {
  Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
  map.put(model.getId(), model.getName());
  return map;
}
```

Comment: This does not seem to be correct. You don't get `Map<String, Integer> valuesByName` here, do you.

Comment: @lexicore I think it is details: the OP can adjust this code to produce a map. The idea is correct

Comment: @Andremoniy See the other comment. Does not seem to be OK for me.

Comment: OP doesn't ask for a `java.util.Map`, the `Map` was only in OPs implementation to store the data during transformation.

Comment: @Andremoniy No, it's not just "details". You have to create a map of `valuesByName`.

Comment: @A.Bandtock `ModelB` specifically requires `Map<String, Integer> valuesByName` in the constructor. So OP *does* ask for `Map`. You can't just pass a string `name` instead of this and pretend nothing happenned.

Comment: Gotcha, sorted.

Comment: `Map.of` does not work as well. You have to group instances of `ModelA` by `id` and for each group create a map, from several instances. This is what the code in the question does.

Comment: This doesn't work since you cannot construct the second parameter (map) of ModelB till you have seen all (name,value) pairs for a particular id.